# Content tabs and select option value to display data ( jquery and php)

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating content tabs that are showing data depending on the chosen value in the select box list. My problem is that I can´t figure out how to setup that the value of the chosen item(league) stays so all three tabs show data from the chosen item (league). For easier understanding I am trying to do is if the user has chosen Premier League the tabs will show the standings, results and goalscorers from that league.
Here is my code:
HTML:

```
     <!Doctype html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src=jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <ul id="nav">
     <li><a href="tab1">Standings</a></li>
     <li><a href="tab2">Results</a></li>
     <li><a href="tab3">Goalscorers</a></li>
     <li><select name="selecting" class="selecting">
     <option value="0">--Choose a league--</option>
     <?php
      $sql=mysql_query("select * from leagues ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 6");
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
       {
        $id=$row['id'];
       $data=$row['name'];
       echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>'; } ?>
      </select></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="content"> </div>
```

Jquery (script.js)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".selecting").change(function()
   {
   var id=$(this).val();
   var dataString = 'id='+ id;

   $.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "tab1.php",
   data: dataString,
   dataType: "html",
   cache: false,
   success: function(data)
   {
   $("#content").html(data).show();
   } 
   });
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "tab2.php",
   data: dataString,
   dataType: "html",
   cache: false,
   success: function(data)
   {
   $("#content").html(data).show();
   } 
   });

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "tab3.php",
   data: dataString,
   dataType: "html",
   cache: false,
   success: function(data)
   {
   $("#content").html(data).show();
   } 
   });
   });


    $('#content').load('tab1.php');
$(' ul#nav li a ').click(function() {
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content').load(page + '.php');
return false;

});
    });
```

Here is a tab file, all three are the same just the sql queries are different.
tab2.php

```
@$id=$_POST['id'];
if(!empty($id))
{
$mysql = mysql_query(" SELECT * from results WHERE leagueid = '$id' ORDER BY matchday asc LIMIT 10 ");
$matchday = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql)) {
if($matchday != $row['matchday']) {
$matcday = $row['matchday'];
echo 'Matchday: '.$row['matchday'].'<br>';
}
    echo ''.$row['hteam'].'  '.$row['hgoals'].' : '.$row['agoals'].'  '.$row['ateam'].'<br>';
}`
```

I thank in advance for the help.
Best regards.

Comment: You are adding three listeners for the same class with different ajax

Answer (score 0):

hey please edit your code if you have coded the same then please ping again because the written here is full of bugs like described bellow

1. You have not initialized the jquery(`$(document).ready(function(){});`)
2. You have a php syntax error on the page where you are extracticting the result
3. You have coded a very bad script.

Comment: could you provide me a link to the page